# Filter to act on already filtered message

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

so, my current problem is that I want to filter an email after it is already moved to a specific label.

Label A
Sublabel aa
Sublabel bb
Sublabel cc

What I want to do is after the email has been filtered into Label A, I want to further filter it by having those emails moved to Sublabel bb.

Comment: Filters act when messages arrive.

Comment: Do you really want them moved? If you move an email from a label they are removed from the current label. Or do you want to apply another filter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to label an email with to different labels you have to create two filters, which applies the labels to the email. Each filter can only apply one label.

**For example:**

Filter 1:
*From: test@test.se

Apply label: Label A*

Filter 2:
*From: test@test.se

Apply label: Sublabel bb*

**As @*Al E.* said in his comment, this only works when receiving an email, there are no other triggers for filters.
There is no way to trigger a filter when moving an email to a label.**